# $y$ is a transient state then $\rho_{xy} \le \rho_{yy}$

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

This is question 16 in Chapter 1 of Hoel, Port, Stone (Introduction to Stochastic Processes)

> Let $y$ be a transient state. Then for all $x$,
> $$\sum_nP^n(x,y)\le \sum_nP^n(y,y)$$

I have already proven that if $y$ is transient then $$E_x[N_y] = \frac {\rho_{yy}} {1-\rho_{xy}}$$
This reduces the above problem to proving $\rho_{xy}\le\rho_{yy} $ for all $x$
I tried to proceed but I got caught in a loop and transformed the problem back to the original one. Any hints on how to proceed? I think the following decomposition might help but I'm not sure how
$$\rho_{yy} = P(y,y)+\sum_{z\ne y}P(y,z)\rho_{zy}$$

I think all the notations used are standard. I'll clarify them if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is the range of the sum over $n$. Does it include $n=0$ or not? Note that your expression $\mathbb{E}_x(N_y)=\frac{\rho_{yy}}{1-\rho_{xy}}$ does **not** include $n=0$ for the case $x=y$.

Here the original statement you are asked to prove isn't true unless you **do** include $n=0$ in the sum (imagine a Markov chain where the only transitions are $x\to y\to z$).

If you do include $n=0$ then $\sum_{n\ge 0}P^n(x,y)=\rho_{xy}\sum_{n\ge 0}P^n(y,y)$.

Comment: Yes, in the question the sum is supposed to be from $0$. I see that I had applied the theorem wrong. Since $P^0(y,y)=1$, the inequality changes to $\rho_{xy} \le (1-\rho_{yy}) + \rho_{yy}$ which is trivially true. Is there any intuitive explanation for the last equality you stated? We can apply the theorem I stated and then it is true but I seem to be missing the direct explanation.

Comment: @Anvit Condition on the first time you reach $y$, if that ever happens. The expected number of visits from this point on is $\sum_nP^n(y,y)$ by Markov property and time invariance.